# xpra version on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

When I have updated my computer to Ubuntu 16.04, xpra package has updated to v0.15.8.

I have some compatibility problems with this version. I have read that v0.15.x  is an unsupported version and v0.14.x is the current LTS (long term support) release  (https://www.xpra.org/trac/wiki/Versions).

How can I install xpra V0.14.x on ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 7):

Updating to 0.14.x still did not allow me to launch xpra but updating to the latest branch 2.0.x did.

TL;DR copied from my [blog](http://brtknr.com/2017/03/15/permission-issues-with-xpra-on-ubuntu-16-04-when-tunnelling-through-SSH/):

```
# Administrator privileges
sudo su -

# Import the packager's key:
apt-get install curl
curl http://winswitch.org/gpg.asc | apt-key add -

# Xenial Xerus (16.04)
echo "deb http://winswitch.org/ xenial main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winswitch.list;
apt-get install software-properties-common >& /dev/null;
add-apt-repository universe >& /dev/null;
apt-get update;
apt-get install winswitch
```

Comment: Sorry I did not know. Done :)

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and type:

```
cd Desktop/
wget -c http://xpra.org/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/xpra_0.14.35-1_amd64.deb # official deb package from xpra.org
sudo dpkg -i xpra_0.14.35-1_amd64.deb
```

xpra v0.14.x is the current LTS (long term support) release, and xpra_0.14.35-1_amd64.deb is compatible with Ubuntu 16.04.

If you get a broken packages message when updating software, then remove xpra using this command:

```
sudo dpkg -r xpra
```

If you still get a broken packages message when updating software, then it wasn't xpra's fault. You need to solve the broken packages error message first before you install xpra. This should be asked as a separate question however.

Comment: Thanks but now Synaptic Package Managers tells me that I have an error (broken package) and I can not  install software updates.